# Поиск шаблона с помощью grep

Tags: регулярные-выражения, unix, grep

Это учебное задание по утилите grep. Есть файл datebook вот с таким форматом:

```
James Ikeda:834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:45000
Jesse Neal:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:25000
Jose Santiago:385-898-8357:38 Fife Way, Abilene, TX 39673:1/5/58:95600
```

Нужно применить утилиту grep, чтобы вывести определенные строки

1. Вывести все строки, содержащие строку Sun:
   *grep 'Sun' datebook*
2. Вывести все строки, где имена людей начинаются с J: 
       *grep '^J' datebook*
3. Вывести все строки, заканчивающиеся на 700:
       *grep '700$' datebook*
4. **Вывести все строки, которые не содержат 834???**
5. Вывести все строки, с днем рождения в декабре: 
       *grep '/12/' datebook*
6. Вывести все строки с телефонными номерами, начинающимися с 408:
       *grep '438-' datebook*
7. Вывести все строки, содержащие следующую последовательность символов: заглавную букву, четыре строчные буквы, запятую, пробел и одну заглавную букву:
       *grep '[A-Z][a-z]{4}, [A-Z]' datebook*
8. Вывести все строки, в которых фамилия начинается с K или k:
       *grep '^.[a-z]* [Kk]' datebook*
9. **Вывести все строки с их порядковыми номерами, где последнее числовое поле записи состоит из шести цифр???**
10. **Вывести все строки, содержащие слова Lincoln или lincoln???**

Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать пункты 4, 9, 10. И насколько оптимально сделаны остальные?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4 `grep -v '834' datebook`

9 `grep -n '[0-9]\{6\}$' datebook`

10 `grep '[Ll]inkoln' datebook`

всё остальное норм